ASP.NET Azure Login Infinite Loop
I have a web app built on .NET Framework 4.8 that has integrated login with Azure AD. When I log out and try to log in again, it enters an infinite loop of calls to Microsoft until the access failed error appears.
Startup code:
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
     string cookieDays = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cookieDays"];
     string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
     string authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"];
     string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUri"];
     string logoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logoutRedirectUri"];
     app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

     app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
         AuthenticationType = "Cookies",                                              
         CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,                       
         ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(int.Parse(cookieDays))            
     });            
     app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
         new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
         {
             // Sets the client ID, authority, and redirect URI as obtained from Web.config
             ClientId = clientId,                    
             Authority = authority,
             RedirectUri = redirectUri,
             // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it's using the home page
             PostLogoutRedirectUri = logoutRedirectUri,
             Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
             // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token, which contains basic information about the signed-in user
             ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
             // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
             // To only allow users from a single organization, set ValidateIssuer to true and the 'tenant' setting in Web.> config to the tenant name
             // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use the ValidIssuers parameter
             TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
             {                                                
                 ValidateIssuer = false // Simplification (see note below)
             }                   
         }
     );
}

LoginController:
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Auth()
{
    var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
    string email = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;

    using (var entities = new SqlProdDbContext()) 
    {
        Utenti user = entities.Utenti.Where(u => u.Email == email).SingleOrDefault();

        if (user == null) 
        {
            Users temp = new Users();
            temp.LoginErrorMessage = "Utente non valido";
            return View("Index", temp);
        }
    }

    Session["userName"] = userClaims?.FindFirst("name")?.Value;
    Session["UserEmail"] = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;
    Session["Roles"] = "1";           
    Session["name"] = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value.Split('@')[0];           

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

public void SignOut()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();                        
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
    HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
}

public ActionResult ClearSession()
{
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();
    //Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}     

I've tried all the solutions I found online, but none of them worked

Are you trying to log in to your account with the ASP.net web app(4.8) using the Microsoft identity platform or a normal app?

Why you are specifying Authorize attribute to the LoginController? You should use the Authorize attribute only to protect the Controller.

Can you share the error screenshot or in text in the above question?

Can you please share your code repo?
